# Blackberry android-runtime : In- app billing not working with Google IAP v2

Tags: android, blackberry, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, blackberry-android

I have integrated Google in-app billing v2 for Blackberry and when i install the app on Blackberry play book i get this error:

```
Error: problem setting up in-app billing: false
```

When i check this method it says:`false if there was an error connecting to Android Market`

this is the method:

```
if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported()) {
        showAlert("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + mBillingService.checkBillingSupported());
    }
```

what am i missing?

**UPDATED**

The above **issue "Error: problem setting up in-app billing: false" was solved and now i am facing this issue.**

When i sending request itseft fails, my request code is

```
Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request); // mservice - IMarketBillingService
PendingIntent pendingIntent  = response.getParcelable(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_PURCHASE_INTENT);
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Error with requestPurchase");
              return Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_INVALID_REQUEST_ID;
        }
```

I checked the responsecode, that return value 5 (i.e) developer_error. and pendingIntent object become null. After that i can't proceed the next step. Even When i checked the support for IAP through code, code return false value.

I am not able to proceed further, please help me.

I have posted question on Blackberry forums also, but i havent got any solution till now.
Link :http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Android-Inapp-purchase-response/td-p/2074235/page/2

Comment: It seems that what you're missing is quite clear: you're missing support for in-app billing! Last time I checked (a long time ago), the Blackberry was not a Google experience Android device which means it has only the publicly available components but not the Google Play store application (and not other Google proprietary apps). Is this still the case? That would be a clear reason why in-app purchasing isn't supported if it is.

Comment: I'm aware (at a high level) of the infrastructure required to make Google Play apps work. I'm also aware of how to use Google (the web search), and when doing it for "in app purchase on blackberry android" I am taken to http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_inapp_payments_support.html as the _top_ link, which states as its first line **The BlackBerry Runtime for Android supports in-app payments through BlackBerry World**. Finally, I'm aware that BlackBerry World is _not_ Google Play. Now... why do you want to know what I've worked on? It's not relevant.

Comment: +1 for the question that you are trying to implement, let me know if you found any solution for it.

Comment: @Maulik sure will let you know, if you find any threads related to blackberry in app billing using google in app billing v2 please let me know

Comment: @Goofy You're getting a developer error because your application isn't eligible for in-app billing. Firstly, be aware that Google Play In-App Billing *doesn't work* on devices that do not have Google Play installed, for instance Blackberry devices. Secondly, you should confirm that you are using either a test purchase (see the IAB documentation) or have signed your application with the same release keystore as the APK that you've uploaded (but not necessarily published) on Google Play.

Comment: I believe I may have misinterpreted your question. There does indeed appear to be a way of getting IAB v2 to interface with Blackberry's native In-App Purchasing, [as this user describes in a forum post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Is-in-app-billing-API-v3-supported/m-p/2595611/highlight/true#M5712).

Answer (score 4):

Applications running in Android do not automatically have access to the Google Play store for in-app billing/purchasing. This feature requires the device to support the Google Play application which is not a part of the open source Android platform; rather it's available only to vendors that license the Google Android experience from Google (which includes several Google applications). The BlackBerry is not one of these environments, so what you're trying to do is unsupported.

Details on how to get some form of in-app billing to work on the BlackBerry Android environment can be found at http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_inapp_payments_support.html.